# Query Clash Royale API

Tags: httprequest

The game Clash Royale is an online, real time, multiplayer game. Therefore, it must have a database to store all of the info. I am wondering if you can, and how, query the database/api.

I want to be able to get player info. I know this is possible, as [Stats Royale](http://statsroyale.com/) successfully does this. They do calculations in their own server, so I found nothing in their client-side code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In which language? What have you tried so far? What specifically are you struggling with? Have you discovered the API endpoint, or do you expect us to find that for you as well?

Comment: If you can play it using a Chrome, you might be able to inspect the requests using [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/). Otherwise I'd suggest [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to snoop the traffic. If you're not yet committed to a programming language, then I'd suggest [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supercell just lauched the official clash royale api: https://developer.clashroyale.com/

I think that this question is in the wrong place though.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to look at http://docs.cr-api.com/#/
They are building a really nice api that provide data in json format about clash royale profiles

Answer (score 0):

Currently Clash of Clans has a Beta API you can register for an use at:
https://developer.clashofclans.com

Comment: Clash Royal and Clash of Clans are different games. Clash of clans has an official API whereas the Clash Royale does not.